# Can't display readable result in my custom LinkedList

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to implement my custom LinkedList, with similar logic. Instead of generics and the Node class, I use my Element class. I only got one problem with one method. Perhaps I forgot or did not get enough sleep, but I cannot remember how to correctly display the values.

Here is some of the code from this class.

```
public class MyLinkedList implements MyList {

    private int size = 0;

    private Entity first;

    private Entity last;


    public MyLinkedList() {
    }

    static class Entity {
        int value;
        Entity next;
        Entity prev;

        public Entity(Entity prev, int value, Entity next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }

interface MyList {

    void add(int value);

    MyList subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex);

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList();
        list.add(13);
        list.add(47);
        list.add(65);
        list.add(6);

        System.out.println(list.subList(0, 2));
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int value) {
        Entity last = this.last;
        Entity newData = new Entity(last, value, null);
        this.last = newData;
        if (last == null)
            first = newData;
        else
            last.next = newData;
        size++;
    }


    @Override
    public MyList subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        MyLinkedList result = new MyLinkedList();
        for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) {
            Entity entity = getEntity(i);
            result.add(entity.value);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Entity getEntity(int index) {
        if (index > size) return null;
        else {
            Entity element = first;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                element = element.next;
            return element;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyLinkedList{" +
                ", first=" + first +
                ", last=" + last +
                '}';
    }
}
```

That is what console outputs:

MyLinkedList{, first=linkedlist.MyLinkedList$Entity@378bf509, last=linkedlist.MyLinkedList$Entity@5fd0d5ae}

What needs to be done to display the resultlike this?

[13, 47, 65]

Answer (score 0):

```
interface MyList {

    void add(int value);

    MyList subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex);

}
public class MyLinkedList implements MyList {

    private int size = 0;

    private Entity first;

    private Entity last;


    public MyLinkedList() {
    }

    static class Entity {
        int value;
        Entity next;
        Entity prev;

        public Entity(Entity prev, int value, Entity next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return Integer.toString(value);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyLinkedList list = new MyLinkedList();
        list.add(13);
        list.add(47);
        list.add(65);
        list.add(6);

        System.out.println(list.subList(0, 2));
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int value) {
        Entity last = this.last;
        Entity newData = new Entity(last, value, null);
        this.last = newData;
        if (last == null)
            first = newData;
        else
            last.next = newData;
        size++;
    }


    @Override
    public MyList subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        MyLinkedList result = new MyLinkedList();
        //i<=toIndex
        for (int i = fromIndex; i <= toIndex; i++) {
            Entity entity = getEntity(i);
            result.add(entity.value);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private Entity getEntity(int index) {
        if (index > size) return null;
        else {
            Entity element = first;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                element = element.next;
            return element;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        /*return "MyLinkedList{" +
          ", first=" + first +
          ", last=" + last +
          '}';
          */
        int start=0;
        String str="";
        while (start < size){
            str+=Integer.toString((getEntity(start).value))+" ";
            start++;

        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

### Compiling & running :

```
$ javac MyLinkedList.java  && java MyLinkedList 
13 47 65
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but that works too, thanks